# Always display bootstrap-datepicker, not just on focus

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using the bootstrap-datepicker library to create a datepicker to let the user choose the date. I would like to *always* display the picker, not just when the user clicks on an input field or a button.

How can I do this?

[image: Picture of a datepicker]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, make sure you're using [the latest version](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/) of the library, which is currently 1.2.0. The [original version](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) by eyecon is pretty poorly documented and I don't know if it can do what you want.

There are a couple of ways to solve your problem. Use whichever of these you prefer:

1. Create an [embedded/inline datepicker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/markup.html#inline-or-embedded) and then add a [`changeDate`](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html#changedate) handler to it. You'll want HTML that's something like

   ```
   <input id="my-input">
   <div id="my-datepicker"></div>
   ```

   and the following JavaScript:

   ```
   $("#my-datepicker").datepicker().on('changeDate', function (e) {
       $("#my-input").text(e.format());
   });
   ```

   Note that `e.format` is a convenience method documented on the [events](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html) page of the documentation, and when invoked as it is here, will return a string representing the selected date formatted according to the datepicker's [format string](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#format).

   You'll need to use your own CSS to appropriately position the datepicker if you take this approach.

   Here's a JSFiddle demonstrating this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/4wFJc/3/
2. Use an ordinary [input datepicker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/markup.html#input), explicitly show it on creation, and then replace the datepicker's `hide()` method with a no-op so that it can never be hidden.

   Needless to say, this is an ugly hack that may well cease to work in a future version of the library. I wouldn't suggest using it. It does have the (doubtful) advantage over the inline-block approach that it positions the datepicker for you and includes an arrow connecting it to your `<input>`, though, so I include it for completeness.

   You'll need HTML something like:

   ```
   <input id="my-input">
   ```

   and the following JavaScript:

   ```
   $input = $("#my-input");
   $input.datepicker();
   $input.data('datepicker').hide = function () {};
   $input.datepicker('show');
   ```

   Here's a JSFiddle demonstrating this approach in action: http://jsfiddle.net/4wFJc/4/

Answer (score 0):

I don't use this datepicker so I am not familiar how it is used. The quick and dirty way would be giving the datepicker dropdown-menu class a `.datepicker.CLASSNAME {display: block !important;}`.
This way the dropdown will always be visible.

Comment: At least with [the latest version](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox) of the datepicker the OP is using, this fails because by default clicking off the `<input>` removes the datepicker from the DOM.

Comment: Like I said.. quick and dirty.

Comment: Dirty because it doesn't work. Not so quick because it does not work.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using this datepicker : http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

You can see there is a method : .datepicker('show')

Call this on datepicker object when your $(document).ready()

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure this will immediately show the datepicker but will still cause it to be dismissed on blur of the associated `<input>` field, rather than causing it to be displayed permanently (which is the OP's objective). Certainly, what you've posted doesn't work with [the latest version](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) of bootstrap-datepicker.