# Require Bootstrap date picker always in open mode

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

How can i get Require Bootstrap date picker always in open mode?

I am using bootstrap date picker in one of my application.

Requirement is like date picker should be open when page load and it should be always in open mode after selection as well.

I found that it can manageable through autoclose: false property but, if i click out side of date picker it's getting close.

It should be there always in open mode.

I hope there is any property which can make it possible, Please find following function which i am using.

**HTML**

```
 <input type="text" id="select_date" class="selecteShipDate" />
```

**Script**

```
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>                                                                                       
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#select_date').datepicker({
            format: 'dd MM yyyy',
            autoclose: false
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at Mark Amery's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20960553/1179865). This should work for you too.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $input = $("#select_date");
    $input.datepicker({
        format: 'dd MM yyyy'
    });
    $input.data('datepicker').hide = function () {};
    $input.datepicker('show');
});
```

I here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uwqysjfz/28/)

Comment: the fiddle don't work anymore, it return 404 for bootstrap datepicker files.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#datepicker').datepicker();
    $('#datepicker').on('changeDate', function() {
        $('#my_hidden_input').val(
            $('#datepicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate')
        );
    });

    <div id="datepicker" data-date="12/03/2012"></div>
    <input type="hidden" id="my_hidden_input">
```