# keep bootstrap datepicker always open

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, datetimepicker

want datepicker always visible, not when calendar is clicked.
So i just wanted to know how to achieve that. I'm trying the `KeepOpen = true;` but that is not working. I wonder how could i achieve that.

Here i leave some of the JS and html code for you to check. If you need more references i can give.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () { var bindDatePicker = function() {
    $(".date").datetimepicker({
    useCurrent: false,
    keepOpen: true,
    format:'YYYY-MM-DD',
        icons: {
            time: "fa fa-clock-o",
            date: "fa fa-calendar",
            up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
            down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
        }
    }).find('input:first').on("blur",function () {

        // check if the date is correct. We can accept dd-mm-yyyy and yyyy-mm-dd.
        // update the format if it's yyyy-mm-dd
        var date = parseDate($(this).val());

        if (! isValidDate(date)) {
            //create date based on momentjs (we have that)
            date = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        }

        $(this).val(date);
    });
}
var isValidDate = function(value, format) {
    format = format || false;
    // lets parse the date to the best of our knowledge
    if (format) {
        value = parseDate(value);
    }

    var timestamp = Date.parse(value);

    return isNaN(timestamp) == false;
}

var parseDate = function(value) {
    var m = value.match(/^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)?(\d{1,2})(\/|-)?(\d{4})$/);
    if (m)
        value = m[5] + '-' + ("00" + m[3]).slice(-2) + '-' + ("00" + m[1]).slice(-2);

    return value;
}

bindDatePicker();


 });
```

And here is the div cointaining:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class='col-sm-3'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                        <input type='text' name="datepicker" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="datepicker" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Always display bootstrap-datepicker, not just on focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451153/always-display-bootstrap-datepicker-not-just-on-focus)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use [.show()](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#show) method to keep your `dateTimePicker` visible, note that all the DateTimePicker's functions are reachable via the data attribute e.g.

```
$('.date').data("DateTimePicker").show();
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    
    var bindDatePicker = function() {
        $(".date").datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false,
            keepOpen: true,
            format:'YYYY-MM-DD',
            icons: {
                time: "fa fa-clock-o",
                date: "fa fa-calendar",
                up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
                down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
            }
        }).find('input:first').on("blur",function () {

            // check if the date is correct. We can accept dd-mm-yyyy and yyyy-mm-dd.
            // update the format if it's yyyy-mm-dd
            var date = parseDate($(this).val());

            if (! isValidDate(date)) {
                //create date based on momentjs (we have that)
                date = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            }

            $(this).val(date);
        });
        
        // here show dateTimePicker via js
        $('.date').data("DateTimePicker").show();
    }

    var isValidDate = function(value, format) {
        format = format || false;
        // lets parse the date to the best of our knowledge
        if (format) {
            value = parseDate(value);
        }

        var timestamp = Date.parse(value);

        return isNaN(timestamp) == false;
    }

    var parseDate = function(value) {
        var m = value.match(/^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)?(\d{1,2})(\/|-)?(\d{4})$/);
        if (m)
            value = m[5] + '-' + ("00" + m[3]).slice(-2) + '-' + ("00" + m[1]).slice(-2);

        return value;
    }

    bindDatePicker();


});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-3'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' name="datepicker" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="datepicker" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glade it helped,

Comment: Is there any way to do it in `React` to keep the calendar open always?